# How to pass multi-line text file contents using Windows cmd?

Tags: cmd

I found this Rust script [compress-cidr](https://github.com/rus-cert/compress-cidr) and looking to run it with a large list as a parameter.

In the `.\target\release` directory, I have `compress-cidr.exe` and `test.txt`. On the project's readme, there is an example call to [Aggregate list](https://github.com/rus-cert/compress-cidr#aggregate-list) functionality. I want to use the Aggregate list example against the `text.txt` file contents.

How can I run `.\compress-cidr.exe -6 -a %textFileContents%` ?

Answer (score 0):

This program expects its input on standard input. Cmd supports the same [basic I/O redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) as Unix shells, including `<FILENAME` to redirect standard input from a file and `>FILENAME` to redirect standard output to a file.

```
cd target\release
compress-cidr -6 -a <test.txt
```